# File not attached to Email

Tags: android, email

I try to attach a .png file to an email, but when the email window opens, the attachment has not been added.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("*/*");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    fFileScreenshot=new File(pathSetup()+"/history/screen54.png");
    if(fFileScreenshot.exists()){

        Uri d = Uri.fromFile(fFileScreenshot);
        uris.add(d);
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        co.startActivity(emailIntent);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send multipart mail you need to add `emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTPLE);`